# axios showing Network request failed error in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, axios

I am geting the Network request failed error when i am using the axios in my reactr native ios and android app, Its working fine when i am testing with postman.

```
const getCourseLesson = async () => {
    await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `${API_URL}getCourseLesson`,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(res => {
        let lessonDataList = res.data.data;
        setLessonList(lessonDataList);
      })
      .catch(res => {
        console.log('lesson error ', res);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Share the successful Postman request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with a sample url and its working fine .. are you sure your Api url is correct?

```html
    const getCourseLesson = async () => {
        await axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users?size=2`,
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log('res.data', res.data)
            })
            .catch(res => {
                console.log('lesson error ', res);
            });
    };
```

Comment: Yes it's working good for me also, Thank you for your responce

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the full result of => *url: `${API_URL}getCourseLesson`*

Make sure your ${API_URL} ends with a '/', something like:
*http://localhost:8080/getCourseLesson*

Also your Headers, make sure you add quotes to your ACCEPT:
headers:

{
**'Accept'**: 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},

Comment: It's not necessary to add quotes to Accept